# MySQL Server Cannot Connect After Flush

Tags: mysql

Earlier today MySQL stopped running, I was able to get it back up and running after a reboot, then it went down again, and again. It was weird how it was acting, so ran a bunch of flush commands,

```
FLUSH HOSTS
FLUSH LOGS
FLUSH MASTER
FLUSH PRIVILEGES
FLUSH QUERY CACHE
FLUSH STATUS
FLUSH TABLES
```

After this I tried to connect to the server using MySQL Workbench and ever since then I have not been able to connect. `Can't connect to MySQL server on 'server ip' (10061)`

`Bind address 0.0.0.0`

I do not have firewall enabled at this point, but when it was I had port 3306 allow in and out. Here is the other odd thing, I have an Apache server setup on a different server and I am able to connect to the MySQL server just fine. I actually have a few websites that use the database. This is probably one of the reasons why I ran out of memory.

At this point I am at a loss to figure out why I can no longer connect the the database from the workbench.

```
2015-10-09 13:39:53 1182 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
2015-10-09 13:39:53 1182 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
2015-10-09 13:39:53 1182 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2015-10-09 13:39:53 1182 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.6.19-0ubuntu0.14.04.1-log'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu)
2015-10-09 13:40:11 1182 [Warning] IP address '192.168.2.61' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
2015-10-09 13:40:11 1182 [Warning] IP address '192.168.2.61' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
2015-10-09 20:19:19 1182 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Normal shutdown

2015-10-09 20:19:19 1182 [Note] Giving 0 client threads a chance to die gracefully
2015-10-09 20:19:19 1182 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
2015-10-09 20:19:19 1182 [Note] Shutting down slave threads
2015-10-09 20:19:19 1182 [Note] Forcefully disconnecting 0 remaining clients
2015-10-09 20:19:19 1182 [Note] Binlog end
2015-10-09 20:19:19 1182 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
2015-10-09 20:19:19 1182 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
2015-10-09 20:19:19 1182 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
2015-10-09 20:19:19 1182 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
2015-10-09 20:19:19 1182 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
2015-10-09 20:19:19 1182 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
2015-10-09 20:19:19 1182 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
2015-10-09 20:19:19 1182 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
2015-10-09 20:19:19 1182 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
2015-10-09 20:19:19 1182 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
2015-10-09 20:19:19 1182 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
2015-10-09 20:19:19 1182 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
2015-10-09 20:19:19 1182 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
2015-10-09 20:19:19 1182 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
2015-10-09 20:19:19 1182 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
2015-10-09 20:19:19 1182 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
2015-10-09 20:19:19 1182 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
2015-10-09 20:19:19 1182 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
2015-10-09 20:19:19 1182 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
2015-10-09 20:19:19 1182 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
2015-10-09 20:19:19 1182 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
2015-10-09 20:19:19 1182 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
2015-10-09 20:19:19 1182 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
2015-10-09 20:19:19 1182 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
2015-10-09 20:19:19 1182 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
2015-10-09 20:19:19 1182 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
2015-10-09 20:19:19 1182 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
2015-10-09 20:19:19 1182 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
2015-10-09 20:19:19 1182 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
2015-10-09 20:19:19 1182 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'InnoDB'
2015-10-09 20:19:19 1182 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2015-10-09 20:19:19 1182 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2015-10-09 20:19:20 1182 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 799648060
2015-10-09 20:19:20 1182 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
2015-10-09 20:19:20 1182 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
2015-10-09 20:19:20 1182 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
2015-10-09 20:19:20 1182 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2015-10-09 20:19:20 1182 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
2015-10-09 20:19:20 1182 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
2015-10-09 20:19:20 1182 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2015-10-09 20:19:20 1182 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
2015-10-09 20:19:20 1182 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_old_password'
2015-10-09 20:19:20 1182 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
2015-10-09 20:19:20 1182 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
2015-10-09 20:19:20 1182 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

2015-10-09 20:19:28 1118 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
2015-10-09 20:19:28 1118 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2015-10-09 20:19:28 1118 [ERROR] Function 'innodb' already exists
2015-10-09 20:19:28 1118 [Warning] Couldn't load plugin named 'innodb' with soname 'ha_innodb.so'.
2015-10-09 20:19:28 1118 [ERROR] Function 'federated' already exists
2015-10-09 20:19:28 1118 [Warning] Couldn't load plugin named 'federated' with soname 'ha_federated.so'.
2015-10-09 20:19:28 1118 [ERROR] Function 'blackhole' already exists
2015-10-09 20:19:28 1118 [Warning] Couldn't load plugin named 'blackhole' with soname 'ha_blackhole.so'.
2015-10-09 20:19:28 1118 [ERROR] Function 'archive' already exists
2015-10-09 20:19:28 1118 [Warning] Couldn't load plugin named 'archive' with soname 'ha_archive.so'.
2015-10-09 20:19:28 1118 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-10-09 20:19:28 1118 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-10-09 20:19:28 1118 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2015-10-09 20:19:28 1118 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
2015-10-09 20:19:28 1118 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2015-10-09 20:19:28 1118 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-10-09 20:19:28 1118 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2015-10-09 20:19:28 1118 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-10-09 20:19:28 1118 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2015-10-09 20:19:28 1118 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2015-10-09 20:19:28 1118 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2015-10-09 20:19:28 1118 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.19 started; log sequence number 799648060
2015-10-09 20:19:28 1118 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '0.0.0.0'; port: 3306
2015-10-09 20:19:28 1118 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
2015-10-09 20:19:28 1118 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
2015-10-09 20:19:28 1118 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2015-10-09 20:19:28 1118 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.6.19-0ubuntu0.14.04.1-log'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu)
2015-10-09 20:19:34 1118 [Warning] IP address '192.168.2.61' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
```

I am seeing these errors a lot:

```
Version: '5.6.19-0ubuntu0.14.04.1-log'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu)
2015-10-10 08:37:34 2216 [Warning] IP address '192.168.2.50' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
2015-10-10 08:40:34 2216 [Warning] IP address '192.168.2.61' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
2015-10-10 08:56:47 2216 [Warning] IP address '192.168.2.39' could not be resolved: Temporary failure in name resolution
2015-10-10 08:57:14 2216 [Warning] IP address '192.168.2.39' could not be resolved: Temporary failure in name resolution
2015-10-10 08:57:34 2216 [Warning] IP address '192.168.2.39' could not be resolved: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

Comment: Can you provide the mysql error log?

Comment: I provided the logs above from yesterday, it isn't a complete list since it would a lot to put on here. I included the last half of the day. It was fine when I went to bed last night and when I woke up it was back down. I restarted the MySQL service and I am able to connect locally but no remote connections. Memory is less than 50% of available. I tried DROPING the users and CREATING them, no luck. Only localhost connections are allowed. Now my webserver isn't connecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I read, you may want to stop DNS reverse lookups by MySQL. Add this you to the my.cnf and see if that resolves.

```
[mysqld]
skip-host-cache
skip-name-resolve
```

I also read you can just add `skip_name_resolve` only in the `my.cfg` to switch that off and that too may work.

Moreover it seems your server is having problems performing DNS lookups, so you may want to check that the DNS configuration is correct (e.g. look at `/etc/resolv.conf`).

Comment: Thank you, I just added `skip-name-resolve` to the config file and rebooted the service. Hopefully this works, I won't know right away because it usually takes a few hours.

Comment: So far so good, I set some monitors up to keep an eye on things over night. Thanks for checking up, I was really worried because there are websites that connect to this.